# How can I generate a PDF of the current web page on button click?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, browser

How can I create and download a PDF version of the current web page (which is open in browser) on button click?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you use jquery on client-side.

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
window.print();
});
```

Which will guide you to print menu where you can choose "Save as PDF" which will save your current view as pdf.
Did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Nuget package: Rotativa http://nuget.org/packages/Rotativa. It's based on wkhtmltopdf.

Usage is really simple.

Having an action you would like to serve as Pdf, instead of Html page. You can define an action that returns an ActionResult of the type ActionAsPdf (RouteAsPdf is also available). So the code is just:

```
public ActionResult PrintIndex()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}
```

With name = "Giorgio" being a route parameter.

Look at this [GitHub](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa)

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting you right. You want to generate a PDF from HMTL. Rotativa plugin is a good choice. Also, mentioned by Janmejay Kumar. If you want to implement this plugin. Please ask if you have any doubt .I have used this plugin for PDF and for image generation.